If $n$-th roots of $1$ are isomorphic for two torsion abelian groups $G$ and $H$, then $G\cong H$?
Using multiplicative notation, for an abelian group $G$, let's define $U_n(G):=\{x\in G:x^n=1\}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This $U_n(G)$ is always a subgroup of $G$. Now, let's assume that for some two torsion abelian groups $G$ and $H$ we have $U_n(G)\cong U_n(H)$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Does this imply $G\cong H$? I have proven this in case when $U_n(G)$ is finite for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but the proof is a little bit weird and it really cannot generalize to the non-finite case. Can someone please share any insight?

It turns out to be a no. Every abelian torsion group is a direct sum of cyclic groups and Prüfer groups. Localize it mod $p$. If there are finitely many cyclic components, then the answer is yes, otherwise we cannot always determine the number of Prüfer components from the given data about the groups.
